# Scala XML pattern matching, top level element

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

Consider the following XML node:

```
 <Interval>
   <P v="1"/>
   <Q v="0.0"/>
  </Interval>
```

What is the correct way to pattern match the top level element in Scala? I would expect the following to work but it does not:

```
def visit(node:Node):String = {
    node match {
        case p @ <P/> => (p \ "@v") text
        case q @ <Q/> => (q \ "@v") text
        case <Interval> @ children:_* </Interval> => "parent"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create an XML literal in Scala, the variable you assign to it *is* the top level element.

```
val node: scala.xml.Elem =
  <Interval>
   <P v="1"/>
   <Q v="0.0"/>
  </Interval>
```

To match the top-level element, here `Interval`, or any element of `Interval` that has child elements like your example, you can use curly braces to match the children.

```
node match {
  case <Interval>{ children @_* }</Interval> => children.collect {
    case p @ <P/> => p \@ "v"
    case q @ <Q/> => q \@ "v"
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
Seq("1", "0.0")
```

If you're not familiar with `collect`, it allows you to provide a partial function (read as "pattern match") and ignore cases that would otherwise fail as a match error.

Comment: I think that this answer mostly gave a more legible and intuitive in regard to original question than mine (on pattern matching syntax, *obviously*). It should be considered as the correct answer. (As for me, I'll use more often this syntax for simple use cases)

Answer (score 0):

This expression in scala:

```
<Interval>
 <P v="1"/>
 <Q v="0.0"/>
</Interval>
```

would definitely return a `scala.xml.Node` in scala but firstly a `scala.xml.Elem`. You can pattern match on it like this:

```
import scala.xml.Elem

def visit(elem: Elem) = {
    elem match {
        case e@Elem(_, "Interval",_, _, _*) => "identified!"
    }
}
```

Or you can pattern match on the `child` as well, because you pattern match on object n of type `Elem`  is like `Elem(n.prefix, n.label, n.attributes, n.scope, n.child)` and here `child` elements (it's a `Seq`) are matched against each remaining elements of the pattern:

```
def visit(elem: Elem) = {
    elem match {
        case Elem(_, "Interval",_, _, emptyElem, nodeIWant@(<P/>), _*) =>
        (nodeIWant \ "@v").text
    }
}
```

which return `1` here for instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I say "which return 1 here for instance" I may have to clarify that it is a `String` whom representation is `1`. Anyway, don't hesitate to ask for a more specific case if that's not sufficient here.